# Complex analysis question?

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the points of the plane where the following zone is mapped: 
the zone defined by the cardioid $ρ=2 (1+ \cosθ)$ from the analytic branch of the function $w= \sqrt{z}$ ,which takes positive values from the positive half-axis..

how do I even begin to solve this?
The answer on my book (not homework) is " the inside of the circle $u^2 + v^2= 2u$ ".......

So ,I am thinking about  expressing $z= ρ \cdot e ^{iθ}$ and $w= r \cdot e^{iΦ}$

Comment: Oh you know you are in trouble when no one in math stack answers :/ It's alright,take your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the square root halves the angle and takes the square root of the norm, so you get

$$
\rho = \sqrt{2(1+\cos(2\theta))} = \sqrt{4\cos^2(\theta)} = 2\cos(\theta).
$$

This traces out the circle $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z-1| = 1\}$.

Comment: How do I put this in terms of u and v? I see no possible relation..thank you anyway :)

Comment: @ciuciu $(u,v) = (2\cos^2(\theta), 2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)) = (1 + \cos(2\theta), \sin(2\theta)) = (1,0) + (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$.

Comment: So the answer in my book is wrong? I feel very very confused...

Comment: @ciuciu Since $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$ you have $(u-1)^2 + v^2 = 1$, or $u^2 + v^2 = 2u$.

Comment: Thank you very,very very much :)